# Wireless networking with LINKSYS router WRT310n v.2 in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu Precise Pangolin 12.04 yesterday. I'm very excited about the change! I've been using windows since I was 16 years old. I'm now 29.... Now, to business.

I'm having trouble establishing a functional wireless connection with my current router (WRT310n) and the Linksys Wireless- G network adapter (WUSB54G v.4). Often times the network manager will even tell me that I have established a connection, but it won't get me on-line. I was wondering if I should just fork out the money to buy a router that I'm sure is Linux compatible or should I try to fix this?

Here is an ifconfig :

```
    brettnruth@SupaflyV:~$ ifconfig
    eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:19:d1:18:69:6f  
              inet addr:192.168.1.101  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
              inet6 addr: fe80::219:d1ff:fe18:696f/64 Scope:Link
              UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
              RX packets:1419 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
              TX packets:1396 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
              collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
              RX bytes:1348283 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:160713 (160.7 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:35403 (35.4 KB)  TX bytes:35403 (35.4 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:18:f8:ad:01:2d  
          inet addr:10.42.0.1  Bcast:10.42.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::218:f8ff:fead:12d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:10477 (10.4 KB)
```

Comment: We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: We need to know the chipset of the network adapter if possible, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue with my Ubuntu 12.04 laptop (Centrino Wireless-N 1030).  I was able to connect to the wireless network, but could not even ping the router, let alone any other host.

After I changed my WPA secured network's mode to be "Wireless-G Only" (Linksys WRT110 Router), my laptop was actually able to use the network.  It happened right away, I did not have to change anything on my laptop's configuration to get past the problem.

Thanks for posting the suggestion to change the Network Mode!  I would not have thought of that!  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with my Linksys router (although it's a different one) and Ubuntu 12.04 too - the small network applet at the top of the screen said i was connected, but i couldn't even ping the router. It was miraculously solved after i set my router's "Network Mode" to "Wireless G only"... Let me know if this works!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after much toil and sorrow. I make it work, by simply resetting the WRT54G Linksys router to factory conditions and setting up just wpa with tkip and mac filter, and finally all working very well, so I think it's worth trying. Best regards to all.
Lenovo Ideapad U410
Intel Core I5
8 Gb Ram
Ubuntu 12.04